# Flutter FireStore, Get document by Document key

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Getting a Document by .documents[x]  where x is zero based document number works in this example.  How would I get the Document by a Keyvalue?
for example, the 3 document would have a key of "qwwe"

how could I get this Document?
Snapshot.data.document["qwwe"]?

this is the code that is working with the code question code // out.

```
//=======   this works
//      body: new ListOfNACS01(),

        body: new StreamBuilder(
//          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('COMPLEX_NONACS').document('A01B01C01D02').snapshots(),
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('COMPLEX_NONACS').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("---  loading ---");
//            return new ListView.builder(
//              itemCount: snapshot.data.document.length,
//            );

              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(snapshot.data.documents[0].documentID),
                  Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]["DE02PRIMARY"]["INDICATION"]),


                  //--------  this does not work  ------------
                  //  how to display a document by DocumentID?
// --  The below line gives error of... 
// error: Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 2 found. 
// (extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named at [scaiqit55] 
// lib/main.dart:48).

                  Text(snapshot.data.document['A01B01C01D01']),
                  Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]["DE02PRIMARY"]["INDICATION"]),


                ],


              );
          },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: after some study...  it appears I should be using this comment...  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14919

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to fetching a Document snapshot using an ID, here's a sample of fetching Cloud Firestore Document snapshot using version ^0.14.3. I've also added a sample on how to fetch a key value from a Document snapshot if that's what you're looking for. You can visit this [FlutterFire cloud_firestore guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#document--query-snapshots) for more details.

```dart
// Collection reference
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('fruits')
  // Document snapshot fetched using ID
  .doc('AQbq33GJ9GE09OaChOPq')
  // Fetches the value inside the Document snapshot using a key
  // value contains a HashMap from the Document snapshot
  .get().then((value) => debugPrint('Fruit name: ${value.data()['name']}'));
```

Here's the data fetched from Firestore

[image: Firestore dashboard]

The expected output from `debugPrint()` is 'Fruit name: Cherry'